# cannot receive json data post from app

Tags: php

I use Yii php to receive data from android and ios app.

I tried postman as below picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaqX0.jpg

But in php, I always receipt "file_get_contents('php://input')":

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryHDGkntVW3uMr7FlA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

e3ma1il@domain.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryHDGkntVW3uMr7FlA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

test223user
------WebKitFormBoundaryHDGkntVW3uMr7FlA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

123456
------WebKitFormBoundaryHDGkntVW3uMr7FlA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstname"

Le
------WebKitFormBoundaryHDGkntVW3uMr7FlA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastname"

Phuong
------WebKitFormBoundaryHDGkntVW3uMr7FlA--
```

How to receive right json encode :(
It's take me 3 days, still not resolved

Comment: Please show us the code for retrieving the data. Do you use curl or some library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Yii2 try to use yii\rest\ActiveController for API controllers and don't forget enable json input. 
More info in yii2 docs - [yii2 rest quick start](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)

p.s. also, you can use "file_get_contents('php://input')" in actions, but i think it is not yii-way.